# Msg 7391, Distributed Transactions (DTC) on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, trigger, linked-server, msdtc, distributed-transactions

This may be DBA related or developer related, I honestly don't know.

I have two Database servers:

```
A: SQL Server 2005 (Trigger that uses DBMail on Server B)
B: SQL Server 2008 R2 (DBMail configured)
```

I have a table in Server A where email notifications are queued and I created an "after insert" trigger to execute `sp_send_dbmail` using Server B like so...

```sql
USE SampleDB
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[mail_inserted] 
   ON [dbo].[tblEmailQueue]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    declare @MailTo nvarchar(max), @MailSubject nvarchar(max), @MailBody nvarchar(max)
    -- Initialize vars
    select @MailTo=MailTo from inserted
    select @MailSubject=MailSubject from inserted
    select @MailBody=MailBody from inserted

    -- Send email via DbMail on ServerB
    exec [ServerB].msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail --this runs fine by itself, but not via trigger
        @profile_name = 'Test Profile'
        ,@from_address = 'noreply@test.com'
        ,@recipients = @MailTo
        ,@subject = @MailSubject
        ,@body = @MailBody
END
```

Here's where the weirdness begins that I need help with, mind you this seems to be a very poorly documented (or severely lacking thereof) feature.

Now I can execute that last statement with some sample data and everything works just fine. But when I try to insert into the table like so...

```sql
insert dbo.tblEmailQueue (MailTo,MailFrom,MailSubject,MailBody) values
    ('to-me@test.com','from-somebody@test.com','Subject','Body')
```

I get the following **ERROR**...

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "ServerB"
    returned message "The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for
    remote/network transactions.".
Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure mail_inserted, Line 15
The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for
    linked server "ServerB" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
```

Perhaps I'm not understanding how Server A is connecting to Server B under the context of the trigger? Do I need to setup a special Login or something? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 7):

I would imagine its either:

```
EXEC sp_serveroption @server = 'ServerB',@optname = 'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue = 'false' ;
```

> Use this option to protect the actions of a server-to-server procedure
>   through a Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC)
>   transaction. When this option is TRUE (or ON) calling a remote stored
>   procedure starts a distributed transaction and enlists the transaction
>   with MS DTC.

Or could be an issue with MSDTC configuration, which is a laborious and lengthy checklist to run through, documented fully in [Recommended MSDTC settings for using Distributed Transactions in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2027550).

Comment: Unfortunately my infrastructure team shut me down on this for now because they are too overloaded, but hopefully I will have a chance to come back to it in one month. If not, I will assume this is a correct answer based on the positive ratings from other users. At any rate, thanks so much for your answer. :)